# If ID contains all elements in vector return TRUE for that ID in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get all id's containing all three times (4,5,6) to return TRUE for every row of that id.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
time <- c(3,4,6,7,2,3,4,6,4,5,6,7)
df1 <- data.frame(id,time)

solution <- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
df_w_sol <- data.frame(df1,solution)
```

I imagine the code would be similar to:

```
df1 %>%
group_by(id)%>%
mutate(if_else(time==c(4,5,6),TRUE, FALSE))
```

I've been trying to use ifelse and %in% function to resolve this but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we need `filter` with `all`.  Create a logical vector with `%in%` and wrap with `all` to get a single TRUE/FALSE output after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(all(4:6 %in% time))
```

NOTE: The OP created a `matrix` with `cbind`.  Inorder to create a `data.frame`, use the `data.frame` constructor.  Also, logical vector `TRUE/FALSE` ('solution') should be without any quotes i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(id, time)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, for the final step how is the last column added to output TRUE/FALSE

Comment: @Sparky if you need a new column, then `%>% mutate(solution = TRUE)` at the end

Comment: Is there any simple way to retain the FALSE values also in the solution?

Comment: @Sparky In that case you don't need to filter, just create a flag column with mutate i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(flag = all(4:6 %in% time))`